# How to get value from a DatePickerSkin in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have these codes for extracting a datepickerskin from a datepicker and place it in an anchorpane. It works well but my problem is how do i get the value from it? Say, when you click on a number like 8 and get the value as a date, just like the datepicker itself?
Here is my code: zig8 is the anchopane.

```
 DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(new DatePicker(LocalDate.now()));
 Region pop = (Region)datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();
 pop.setPrefHeight(zig8.getPrefHeight());
 pop.setPrefWidth(zig8.getPrefWidth());
 zig8.getChildren().add(pop);
```

I tried to attach a mouse event this way:

```
 pop.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,(e)->
 {
         //a code to get the value.

 });
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write value from the datepicker you provided in the DatePickerSkin constructor:

```java
var datepicker = new DatePicker();
var skin = new DatePickerSkin(datepicker);

// read value
datepicker.getValue();

// write value
datepicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());

// bind value property
datepicker.valueProperty().bind(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not very save and could break every time DatePicker gets updated. But lets assume that does not happen :)

If you look at the code of DatePicker, you can see that it structure is roughly:

- DatePickerContent    (*VBox*)

  - MonthYearPane (*BorderPane*)
  - GridPane

    - Contains the Buttons, which are of type *DateCell*

So we can write a function to search the content of the *DatePicker* and find all the *DateCells*. Since they are being reused we need to do this only once. We can then attach an event listener to each *DateCell*

```
    ...
    List<DateCell> dateCells = getAllDateCells(pop);
    DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(new DatePicker(LocalDate.now()));
    DatePickerContent pop = (DatePickerContent)datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();
    pop.setPrefHeight(zig8.getPrefHeight());
    pop.setPrefWidth(zig8.getPrefWidth());
    zig8.getChildren().add(pop);

    List<DateCell> dateCells = getAllDateCells(pop);

    for (DateCell cell : dateCells)
    {
        cell.addEventHandler(
                MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,(e)->
                {
                    System.out.println("Mouse clicked :" + cell.getItem());
                }
        );
    }
    ...



 private static List<DateCell> getAllDateCells(DatePickerContent content)
 {
     List<DateCell> result = new ArrayList<>();

     for (Node n : content.getChildren())
     {
         System.out.println("node " + n + n.getClass());
         if (n instanceof GridPane)
         {
             GridPane grid = (GridPane) n;
             for (Node gChild : grid.getChildren())
             {
                 System.out.println("grid node: " + gChild + gChild.getClass());
                 if (gChild instanceof DateCell)
                 {
                     result.add((DateCell) gChild);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     return result;
 }
```

Since DateCell derives from Cell<> it knows its current date and we can use getItem to figure out the date

**Alternative:**
You could probably get access to the protected DateCell List in DatePickerContent by using Reflection.

```
protected List<DateCell> dayCells = new ArrayList<DateCell>();
```